# What is returned by ResultSet's method getInt() in case column value is between 0 and 1?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

According to my experiments(tests, ok?:)) it is 0, but I cannot find it documented anywhere. So, is it true? 
Update: tested with Oracle 11g and appropriate JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the driver. It could return 0, it could return null or it could throw an Exception. Different drivers might (and probably will) behave differently. The moral is, use the correct call for the underlying type.